# Avoiding notebook re-evaluation after quitting Mathematica

Tags: evaluation, notebooks

I'm new here so I hope I'm not asking something already solved. I'm new to Mathematica and I need to manage lists created from files that usually spend a lot of time to be created. I noticed that saving and then re-opening the notebook basically remove the lists themselves, and I have to re-run the entire code every time, which is boring and a huge loss of time. Is there a way to avoid this issue and be ready to work on the notebook as soon as I open it?

Comment: Look up `LocalObject`, `LocalSymbol`, `Save`, and `DumpSave` in the docs.

Comment: Example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155907/4999

Comment: `Iconize[]` is another way to save data. Unlike the methods in my first comment, which store data in an external file, `Iconize[]` stores data in the notebook but displays only a small icon.

Comment: Duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/193301/26598